# R: How do boosted regression trees deal with missing data?

Tags: r, tree, regression

How does the R implementation of boosted regression trees (package gbm) by default deal with missing values of the predictor variables? Are they imputed and if they are, according to which algorithm?

Background of my question: I did the analysis almost a year ago and I used the scripts provided by Elith et al. 2008 (A working guide to boosted regression trees, Journal of Animal Ecology  77, 802–813) to invoke gbm. I now got aware that I had NAs for some of the predictive variables and I wonder how the boosted regression trees dealt with them. Browsing through various manuals and papers I found statements like "boosted regression trees can accomodate missing values" and the like, but I couldn't find a precise description of what gbm is doing with missing values. The analysis itself ran without problems, so gbm must have dealt with them in one or the other way. In the gbm manual there is even an example where deliberately NAs are introduced to demonstrate that gbm keeps working without problems. Now I'd like to know what gbm precisely does with NAs (skip them, impute them,...?).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation of a statistical algorithm. It is perhaps better suited to Cross Validated.

Comment: @SimonO101: I doubted which one would be the proper forum. I'll post it at Crossvalidated.

Comment: I'd leave it a while - the site is community run. If the consensus is that this is off-topic then the question will get closed and you know to ask on CV. At the moment, its just me who thinks it is better suited to CV!

Comment: Maybe you need to also add some more effort - tell us if you've checked the help file (and for which functions? You don't say) and maybe try some sample analyses with and without NA's to see what happens. For all we know it might fail with an error - have you tried?

Comment: @Spacedman: Thanks for your suggestion, I added more information in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

The gbm function can be used for imputation [as described in Jeffrey Wongs blog:](http://s3l.stanford.edu/blog/?p=73). Missing values get surrogate splits and the user can then get predictions for iems with incompleted predictor sets.

He has developed a package based on this approach. The GitHub repo has this in the header to one of the files for gbm:

```
#' GBM Imputation
#'
#' Imputation using Boosted Trees
#' Fill each column by treating it as a regression problem. For each
#' column i, use boosted regression trees to predict i using all other
#' columns except i. If the predictor variables also contain missing data,
#' the gbm function will itself use surrogate variables as substitutes for the predictors.
#' This imputation function can handle both categorical and numeric data.
```

To find this I merely typed this into a Google search: how does gbm deal with missing values. It was the 2nd hit for me.

https://github.com/jeffwong/imputation/blob/master/R/gbmImpute.R

Comment: That looks like the `gbmImpute` function in the `imputation` package, not the `gbm` package as asked...

Comment: Does the added code using gbm in Wong's blog answer the question. I did find another SO Q&A from earlier this year but I didn't think any of the answers explained the imputation process as well as Wong did.

Comment: Jeff Wong's is a great piece of code and the header note does answer the OP's question at a high level. As I understand it, the OP is asking about how missing values are treated by the gradient boosting algorithm as implemented in package gbm. The short answer is that they are explicitly handled as a type of split along with left and right splits, and a surrogate split method is applied (cf. documentation on ada and rpart packages).